# How can I paint uniform sized textures on large surfaces?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I've just started discovering the paint tool, but no matter what I press in the brush options or size up and down, when I zoom out of the model in the 3d view and when I zoom in while painting, the textures are of different sizes. In Photoshop as an example no matter how much zoomed in or our you are, if the brush is set to 15 pixels, it will always paint in 15 pixels.

So what do I have to do (hopefully without the nodes) in order to paint in the same thickness, regardless of the level of zoom.

Btw. I spent the entire day trying to find an exact answer to this, so if there is one, please reply with an exact answer rather than ,,duplicate". I've had duplicated topics a few times and those duplicate threads were never the same thing I asked, slightly similar, but not the same thing and I still have no idea what the answers are to those topics that got duplicated..

Comment: If answer is closed as duplicate then you phrased it in a way others understand as a it already has an answer. If it doesn't fit your situation please do your best and explain why not. Not all questions on this site will get an answer in the Answer field below according to the site rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you paint in the 3d view, the brush will increase based on your view. If you instead use the UV/2d Image Editor, then you will see a more constant relationship with the brush size/texture size. There are benefits to both behaviors, but hopefully this helps you get farther along.